# Populating a pivot table with Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack

I have 8 tables: products, pests, actives, crops, active_product, pest_product, crop_product, and active_pest

I've built a form that loads information about a selected (agrichemical) product - in that form, the user selects the pests, actives, and crops associated with that product.  When submitted, my existing code is saving the expected information in the products table and, through a set of "belongsToMany" relationships, the active_product, pest_product, and crop_product pivot tables are also correctly updated.

My problem is that I do not know how to use the actives and pests information (i.e. their respective id values) to add to/update the active_pest table.

I'd appreciate some direction.

The methods in my models are as follow:

**product**

```
public function Actives()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Active','active_product', 'product_id', 'active_id');
}
public function pest()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pest','pest_product', 'product_id', 'pest_id');
}
public function active()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Active','active_product', 'product_id', 'active_id');
}
```

**active**

```
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'active_product', 'active_id', 'product_id');
}

public function pest()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pest', 'active_pest', 'active_id', 'pest_id');
}
```

**pest**

```
public function active()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Active', 'active_pest', 'pest_id', 'active_id');
}
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product','pest_product', 'pest_id', 'product_id');
}
public function crop()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Crop','crop_pest', 'pest_id', 'crop_id');
}
```

I am using BackPack for Laravel - my Product controller contains this function for updating:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{    
    $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);
    return $redirect_location;
}
```

updateCrud is

```
public function updateCrud(UpdateRequest $request = null)
{
    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('update');
    $this->crud->setOperation('update');

    // fallback to global request instance
    if (is_null($request)) {
        $request = \Request::instance();
    }

    // update the row in the db
    $item = $this->crud->update($request->get($this->crud->model->getKeyName()),
                        $request->except('save_action', '_token', '_method', 'current_tab', 'http_referrer'));
    $this->data['entry'] = $this->crud->entry = $item;

    // show a success message
    \Alert::success(trans('backpack::crud.update_success'))->flash();

    // save the redirect choice for next time
    $this->setSaveAction();

    return $this->performSaveAction($item->getKey());
}
```

Thanks, Tom

Comment: isn't it working similar to the other ones? as in the naming conventions seems to be alright. What issue you're facing? What methods you've on `Active` model? and you're saving the data to the table and pivot table?

Comment: My Active model contains 
   public function pest() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pest', 'active_pest', 'active_id', 'pest_id');
}

and my Pest model contains
   public function active() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Active', 'active_pest', 'pest_id', 'active_id');
    }

Comment: Edit your question, and show us the relevant code. There is nothing here for us to go on - why are you able to update some pivots, but not others?  What is the specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel's [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method like this:

```
$actives = App\Active::create([
    'someColumn' => 'test',
    'anotherColumn' => 'test',
]);

$pests = App\Pest::create([
    'someColumn' => 'test',
    'anotherColumn' => 'test',
]);

$actives->pest()->attach($pests);
          ^^^-relation name in model
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. After reading about attach(), sync(), and SyncWithoutDetaching(), I've gone with the latter as I need a unique set of data that isn't going to be deleted with each new product processed.